# How to update table cell value in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I ma new to jquery.
I would like to update the table cell from Jquery.
The Php is as below.
For example I would like to update "firsttotal" with a different value. Please help.

```
<tr>
                        <td class="Left">Total</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td id="firsttotal"><?php echo number_format('%.2n', $Total_Calculated_Cash); ?></td>
                        <td id="cashcalculator_total"><a href="#"><?php echo number_format($Total_Actual_Cash, 2); ?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo number_format($Total_Calculated_Other, 2); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo number_format($Total_Actual_Other, 2); ?></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: Just a general comment on the use of ID selectors - I would recommend not prefixing with 'td' as ID's are "supposed" to be unique and if the page layout changes (for example) to a div later to help with layout etc, the JS code will not break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since anchor is inside TD, you should use jQuery('td#cashcalculator_total a')

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('td#cashcalculator_total a').html('XXX');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the td element and set the value like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newValue = 6;
    $("#firsttotal").text(newValue);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td#firsttotal').html(value);
```

or

```
$('td#firsttotal').text(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#firsttotal').html("new Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td#firsttotal').text(value)
```

so something like this would work

```
$('td#firsttotal').text("test")
```

If you wanted to add HTML tags into it then you can use this

```
$('td#firsttotal').html("<p>test</p>")
```